# Kivy python callback doesn't work on android device

Tags: python, android, kivy

My app works if I run it on terminal but doesn't work if I install it on a smartphone. It seems the problem is in a callback function because. This is the code:

```
    import certifi
    from kivymd.app import MDApp
    from kivy.lang import Builder
    from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
    from datetime import datetime


class MarsWeatherApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.title = "Weather on Mars"
        self.theme_cls_primary_palette = "Black"
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "200"
        self.icon = "icon.png"
        self.root = Builder.load_file("marsweather.kv")
        return self.weather_load()

    def weather_load(self):

        endpoint = "https://api.mars.spacexcompanion.app/v1/weather/latest"

        self.weather_request = UrlRequest(endpoint, 
                                          on_success=self.get_data,
                                          ca_file=certifi.where())

    def get_data(self, request, response):
       #here I put only 2 lines to simplify example
        season = response["season"]        
        self.root.ids["mdSeasonValue"].text = season
        self.root.ids["mdLabTempValue"].text = "Hello World"


MarsWeatherApp().run()`
```

This works perfectly when I run it on Atom terminal, but when I build the app with buildozer, and install it on a smartphone, I can see all widgets without problems but doesn't change value on labels.
If I put, for example `self.root.ids["mdLabTempValue"].text = "Hello World"` under the weather_load function, after building app with buildozer it works on smartphone.
I don't understand where is the problem.
Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Sounds like the UrlRequest isn't returning. Is htere nothing in the log about it?

Comment: @inclement thanks for answer. I've tried to print response and it gives to me the correct answer. After building the app and installed on the smartphone, it doesn't work and I don't know how to have a log. I'm new with kivy.

Comment: Are you using buildozer?

Comment: @JohnAnderson Yes. Do you need to view buildozer.spec?

Comment: Seeing the `spec` file might help. If you can connect your smartphone and run `buildozer android deploy run logcat`, you may see error messages.

Comment: This is the next step I want to learn. Now I'm searching for instructions to do it. Thanks for your suggestion.